# Observer pattern in Java Play framework

Tags: java, playframework, websocket, observer-pattern

I'm writing a web application with Java Play, and the idea is to have a websocket connect to the server, send a bunch of "live"-data in JSON and have another websocket connect to the server and collect the data. I am trying to implement the observer pattern here, so the server will send data whenever it's updated. I can't seem to get it to work.

So I guess I am asking *how to implement the Observer Pattern within a Java Play application.*
I have tried putting this code in the onStart-method, but I keep getting InstantiationException, which I'm guessing is because the objects are instantiated when a WebSocket connects.

```
WSocket socket = new WSocket(); //Observable
Listener listener = new Listener(socket); //Observer
```

Any tips will be appreciated!

Comment: I might mention that both sockets are working, i.e one socket can send JSON-data and the other one can pick up JSON-data. (Tested separately.)

Comment: How are you handling the Websocket connections? With actors like https://playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/JavaWebSockets ? Which version of Play are you using?

Comment: I am using Play 2.5.1, and I am currently handling my sockets using callbacks :)

Comment: Which WebSocket implementation are you using? In your example is WSocket - but Play's implementation is WebSocket. Also: If you're using callbacks you likely doing the observer pattern already. Defining a callback is the most important part.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Correct me if I am wrong but I think you are overengineering things. If I understand correctly, you want that the data which is sent from one WebSocket connection is populated to the other active WebSocket connections.

---

If you are using callbacks in Play, when the `WebSocket` is ready, you get both `in` and `out` channels.

What you can do is to collect all `out` channels in some `List` and whenever you get some message you just broadcast this message to all of the `out` channels you have collected.

And if you have time consider rewriting the handling of WebSocket connections with Akka actors - it is easier and more stable (and also fun ;)

Comment: You are completely right. This project is super close to becoming spaghetti.
I tried putting the out channels in a list, now it works :)

Comment: Glad that I could help :)